# Group by month and week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, charts

I would like to know what is the best way to group my hash of 
`{date->value}` in month and week.

```
{Sat, 23 Apr 2016=>6.0, Mon, 06 Mar 2017=>9.0, Tue, 04 Apr 2017=>13.0, Tue, 11 Apr 2017=>25.0}
```

I would like a result like:

```
{Apr 2016=>6, Mar 2017=>9, Apr 2017=>38}
```

I tried with Groupdate/Chartkick but I am not getting a good result.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given the desired result for the OP's example, I've assumed that the OP means "month and year" rather than by "week and month".

I also assumed that the keys of the input hash are intended to be strings (rather than date objects) and the keys of the hash returned are intended to be strings. In any event, I would use [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) with a default value of zero (a *counting hash*). See the doc for details.

```
dates = {"Sat, 23 Apr 2016"=>6.0, "Mon, 06 Mar 2017"=>9.0,
         "Tue, 04 Apr 2017"=>13.0, "Tue, 11 Apr 2017"=>25.0}

dates.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(k,v),h| h[k[-8..-1]] += v.to_i }
   #=> {"Apr 2016"=>6, "Mar 2017"=>9, "Apr 2017"=>38}
```

If the dates of the input hash are date objects, we can do the following. First create the date objects.

```
require 'date'

dates =  {"Sat, 23 Apr 2016"=>6.0, "Mon, 06 Mar 2017"=>9.0,
         "Tue, 04 Apr 2017"=>13.0, "Tue, 11 Apr 2017"=>25.0}.
  map { |str, v| [Date.parse(str), v] }.to_h
    #=> {#<Date: 2016-04-23 ((2457502j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>6.0,
    #    #<Date: 2017-03-06 ((2457819j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>9.0,
    #    #<Date: 2017-04-04 ((2457848j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>13.0,
    #    #<Date: 2017-04-11 ((2457855j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>25.0}
```

Then we can write

```
dates.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(k,v),h| h[k.strftime("%b %Y")] += v.to_i }
  #=> {"Apr 2016"=>6, "Mar 2017"=>9, "Apr 2017"=>38}
```

See [DateTime#strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime).

This is a pure-Ruby solution.

Comment: Thanks ! :) its what i need

Answer (score 0):

If you have the hash of data (as a hash) already an option would be to use `reduce`

for the month it would be

```
data.reduce({}) do |memo, (date, value)|
  new_date = date.beginning_of_month.strftime("%B %Y")
  memo[new_date] ||= 0
  memo[new_date] += value
  memo
end
```

for the week it would be

```
data.reduce({}) do |memo, (date, value)|
  new_date = date.beginning_of_week.strftime("%B %e %Y")
  memo[new_date] ||= 0
  memo[new_date] += value
  memo
end
```

You can use [this document](https://apidock.com/ruby/Date/strftime) to modify the `strftime` format however you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Even easier: `data.transform_keys! { |k| k.strftime("%B %Y") }`